# Quickly create class from an interface in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a plugin for eclipse which allows me to quickly generate a new class from an interface?

Rather than having to do the typing in the new class dialog

Ideally letting me choose a standard name like Impl for it to generate

Comment: The "new class" dialog isn't quick enough for you?

Comment: lazy on an epic scale

Comment: Clearly, but I don't see how it could be any faster than it already is... you type the class name, pick the interface, and the wizard will generate a default implementation of that interface... how could that be quicker?

Comment: @skaffman, right click interface -> New implementation. I'm surprised it's not there yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not seen any plugins that do this, but it seems a reasonable shortcut to me.

The following could form the basis for a plugin to generate a class directly from a selected interface. It works on my box(TM).

It currently assumes the class will take the interface name suffixed with "Impl" and fails (logging the reason) if that type already exists.

Some enhancements I can think of:

- allow selection of multiple interfaces
- define a preference page for the implementation suffix and package name
- open a dialogue with the values populated if the "default" implementation already exists

The plugin adds a command to the context menu for editors, views and text selections, disabling the item if the selection doesn't resolve to an interface. It can also be activated with <kbd>ctrl-6</kbd> (you can obviously change the key-bindings in the plugin.xml to suit your mood).

The plugin code is as follows:

```
package name.seller.rich.classwizard.actions;

import java.util.Collections;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.core.expressions.EvaluationContext;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaElement;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaModelException;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.SelectionConverter;
import org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewClassWizardPage;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE;
import org.eclipse.ui.wizards.newresource.BasicNewResourceWizard;

public class GenerateClassHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    public GenerateClassHandler() {
    }

    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        NewClassWizardPage page = new NewClassWizardPage();

        EvaluationContext evaluationContext = (EvaluationContext) event
                .getApplicationContext();

        IWorkbenchPart activePart = (IWorkbenchPart) evaluationContext
                .getVariable("activePart");
        try {
            IStructuredSelection selection = SelectionConverter
                    .getStructuredSelection(activePart);

            IType type = getFirstType(selection);

            if (type != null && type.exists() && type.isInterface()) {
                page.init(selection);

                String typeName = type.getElementName() + "Impl";
                // TODO handle existing type
                page.setTypeName(typeName, true);

                // generate constructors and methods, allow modification
                page.setMethodStubSelection(false, true, true, true);

                page.setSuperInterfaces(Collections.singletonList(type
                        .getFullyQualifiedName()), true);
                try {
                    page.createType(new NullProgressMonitor());

                    IResource resource = page.getModifiedResource();
                    if (resource != null) {
                        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil
                                .getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
                        BasicNewResourceWizard
                                .selectAndReveal(resource, window);
                        openResource((IFile) resource, window);
                    }
                } catch (CoreException e) {
                    // TODO if we get this the type already exists, open a
                    // dialogue to allow the type name to be modified or give
                    // up?
                    logException(e);
                }

            }
        } catch (JavaModelException e) {
            logException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void openResource(final IFile resource, 
            IWorkbenchWindow window) {
        final IWorkbenchPage activePage = window.getActivePage();
        if (activePage != null) {
            final Display display = window.getShell().getDisplay();
            if (display != null) {
                display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            IDE.openEditor(activePage, resource, true);
                        } catch (PartInitException e) {
                            logException(e);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(Object context) {
        if (context != null && context instanceof EvaluationContext) {
            EvaluationContext evaluationContext = (EvaluationContext) context;

            IWorkbenchPart activePart = (IWorkbenchPart) evaluationContext
                    .getVariable("activePart");

            try {
                IStructuredSelection selection = SelectionConverter
                        .getStructuredSelection(activePart);

                IType type = getFirstType(selection);

                if (type != null) {
                    setBaseEnabled(type.isInterface());
                    return;
                }
            } catch (JavaModelException e) {
                logException(e);
            }
        }

        setBaseEnabled(false);
    }

    private IType getFirstType(IStructuredSelection selection) {
        IJavaElement[] elements = SelectionConverter.getElements(selection);

        if (elements != null && elements.length > 0) {
            if (elements[0] != null && elements[0] instanceof IType) {
                return (IType) elements[0];
            }

            try {
                if (elements[0] != null
                        && elements[0] instanceof ICompilationUnit) {
                    IType[] types = ((ICompilationUnit) elements[0])
                            .getAllTypes();

                    if (types != null && types.length > 0) {
                        return types[0];
                    }
                }
            } catch (JavaModelException e) {
                logException(e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void logException(Exception e) {
        JavaPlugin.log(e);
    }
}
```

The plugin.xml to contribute the command is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.0"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
        name="Generate Class"
        categoryId="name.seller.rich.classwizard.category"
        id="name.seller.rich.classwizard.generateClassCommand">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
        commandId="name.seller.rich.classwizard.generateClassCommand"
        class="name.seller.rich.classwizard.actions.GenerateClassHandler">
      </handler>
   </extension>
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
        commandId="name.seller.rich.classwizard.generateClassCommand"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
        sequence="M1+6"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
      </key>
   </extension>
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
     <command
           commandId="name.seller.rich.classwizard.generateClassCommand"
           mnemonic="G">
     </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

and the manifest.mf looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Classwizard
Bundle-SymbolicName: name.seller.rich.classwizard; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.5.0",
 org.eclipse.core.expressions;bundle-version="3.4.100",
 org.eclipse.jface.text;bundle-version="3.5.0",
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui;bundle-version="3.5.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.ide;bundle-version="3.5.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.editors;bundle-version="3.5.0",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.5.0"
Eclipse-AutoStart: true
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

Answer (score 45):

Havn't seen anything other than: right click the interface type in the package explorer, chose **New->Class** and it will automatically implement that interface. You still have to name the new class yourself.

Comment: @user710818 You're maybe right clicking on the .java file in the Package Explorer, not the type (i.e. just expand the .java file containing the interface, and right click the interface type, select New->Class). This works perfectly in Indigo and Helios at least.

Comment: When you select the Interface (not the file), than you can also use the green "new Java class" icon in the top bar.

Answer (score 7):

It was actually asked as soon [as 2002](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools/msg21488.html)

> The refactoring should extract all (switch for "all public") methods
>   from a class, create an interface and rename the old class
>   to Classname*Impl*.

... and entered as a [feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=14293), "resolved "in [ticket 9798](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9798), because the New->Class will have the option "Inherited abstract method" (since at least [Eclipse SDK 2.1](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.aspectj/shadows/org.eclipse.jdt.core/notes/R21_buildnotes_jdt-core.html?root=Tools_Project&view=co) 2003) for you to choose in order to automatically implement those public abstract methods.

[image]

Comment: Are you a contributor? You really seem to know quite a lot about it :)

Comment: @javamonkey79: nope, but some actual eclipse contributors do answer SO questions: see for instance this answer (and its comment): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363584/eclipse-improve-debugging-and-display-vairable-values-on-mouseover/1363640#1363640

Comment: What I'd like to see is New Class dialog pre-filled with my selected interface in the "implements" list.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a class, let it implement an interface.

You get errors, because the methods are not defined. Just Ctrl-1, or right clic, and you can create all methods, with TODOs, javadoc comments and so on as needed (depending on the way your Eclipse is configured).

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**: Right click on the class name, then choose "Quick Fix", and then a small menu will appear, within which you choose: "Add unimplemented methods".

**Method 2**: Right click on the class name, go to "Source", then choose "Override/Implement Methods"